# SQL Query: Return value starting 28 days from parameter date to 56 days after parameter date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I have a query that allows me to return the number of events by EventID that occur from a parameter date (@STARTDATE) to 28 days previous. I would like to be able to return the number of events that occur in the previous 28 days.

```
COUNT (DISTINCT (CASE when EventID between  DATEADD(YEAR,-0,DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @STARTDATE), -28)) and DATEADD(Year,-0,@STARTDATE) then EVentID END)) TwentyEightDays
```

I need to be able to run a similar query where the EVENTID count starts at 29 days from @STARTDATE to 56 days after @STARTDATE.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have not shown a query.  You have shown an expression, presumably using in a `SELECT` or `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers were reverse order but this query worked:

COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN eventdate >= DATEADD(day, -56, @StartDate) AND
                         eventdate <= DATEADD(day, -29, @StartDate)
                         THEN EventId END)

Thank you to Gordon for this help!

Answer (score 1):

To count events from 28 days before to a given date, I would use:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN eventdate >= DATEADD(day, -28, @StartDate) AND
                         eventdate <= @startdate
                    THEN EventId
               END) as TwentyEightDays
```

For 29 days to 56 days after:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN eventdate >= DATEADD(day, 29, @StartDate) AND
                         eventdate <= DATEADD(day, 56, @StartDate)
                    THEN EventId
               END)
```

Note:  This assumes that you have a column for the date in question.  I doubt that is the `EventId`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and it appears to work. Thank you. I will have a larger database to try tomorrow and will reply again. Thank you so kindly for the help.

Comment: I have a larger data sample today and this is not returning results.  If anyone has any more suggestions I would be grateful. I am going to continue to research this today.